# Trying to ping specific roles in Discord based a specific answer from Google Forms - App Scripts

Tags: javascript, discord

Basically as the title says. I run a community of different mmos but was trying to make one Google form for all applications to whichever game/team people want to apply to. The problem is that each game/team have their own recruitment officers and so need to be notified about an application only if it relates to them.

I ensured that each application had very specific roles that someone would apply for - for instance, if applying for an Officer position in Retail WoW, you would have to click a choice that was labeled "Officer (BoB - Retail)". So that when searching through the array, it would be very obvious what they are applying for (and then I can direct what Role within Discord that goes to). As far as I know, Google App Script uses Javascript so was looking at that.

So the code runs, and the application DOES get to the Discord server everytime, however it posts multiple times, printing each question and then reprinting each new question and answer in separate embeds. (for 5 question application, there would be 5 different embeds, each getting longer because it adds a question each time).

Another problem I have is that it ALWAYS pings the last discord ID in my if-else loop.

I'm very newbie when it comes to any type of coding (never done it at all except some basic html when I was 10 years old), and all my googling is no help. I come to you now - with my disastrous code. Any help is much appreciated.

```js
const POST_URL = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/hiddenForObviousReasons";

function onSubmit(e) {
    const response = e.response.getItemResponses();
    let items = [];
  var pingRole;
    
    //get questions and answers into an array
    for (const responseAnswer of response) {
        const question = responseAnswer.getItem().getTitle();
        const answer = responseAnswer.getResponse();
        let parts = []

        try {
            parts = answer.match(/[\s\S]{1,1024}/g) || [];
        } catch (e) {
            parts = answer;
        }

        if (!answer) {
            continue;
        }

        for (const [index, part] of Object.entries(parts)) {
            if (index == 0) {
                items.push({
                    "name": question,
                    "value": part,
                    "inline": false
                });
            } else {
                items.push({
                    "name": question.concat(" (cont.)"),
                    "value": part,
                    "inline": false
                });
            }
        }
  //figure out what role to mention, set it to pingRole 
  if (items.includes("Guild Member (BoB – Retail)")){
     pingRole = "<@&1015422362486841385>"
    }else if(items.includes("Officer (BoB – Retail)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043294570219319407> , <@&1026338739359854652>"
    }else if(items.includes("Team DemonBear (AoTC Raid Team)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1026339267280121866>, <@&1026339669945876540>"
    }else if(items.includes("Team TacoBay (Mythic Raid Team)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1026339414609240154>, <@&1026339795707891773>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Member (TC - Retail)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043296376638935080>"
    }else if(items.includes("Officer (TC - Retail)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043295820453257227>"
    }else if(items.includes("Community Membership")){
    pingRole = "<@&1026337990064222228>"
    }else if(items.includes("Community Leadership (become part of The Council)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1014799407847329843>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Leadership")){
    pingRole = "<@&1026337808476028958>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Member (BoB - MC)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298055841124413>"
    }else if(items.includes("Officer (BoB - MC)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298205653282947>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Member (BoB - GC)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298341720686602>"
    }else if(items.includes("Officer (BoB - GC)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298457613504522>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Member (FF - LF)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298800812437554>"
    }else if(items.includes("Officer (FF - LF)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043298944366694510>"
    }else if(items.includes("Guild Member (FF - E)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043299430411022477>"
    }else if(items.includes("Raider Position (TC - Retail)")){
    pingRole = "<@&1043295820453257227>"
    }else(items.includes("Officer (FF - E)"))
    pingRole = "<@&1043299594156642414>"

    //embed message details and pingRole outside of the embed    
    const options = {
        "method": "post",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        "payload": JSON.stringify({
            "content": "" + pingRole,
            "embeds": [{
                "title": "New application here!",
                "color": 33023,
                "fields": items,
                "footer": {
                    "text": "End of application."
                },
                "timestamp": new Date().toISOString()
            }]
        })
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(POST_URL, options);
      }
};
```